# Keycloak: get identity provider info

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I have spring boot app and I use **keycloak** as auth. provider.

For my realm I have set **FACEBOOK or GOOGLE as identity providers**.

I wonder how can I find out what identity provider user used - NOT via keycloak admin console, BUT in runtime.

---

eg.:

user A - FACEBOOK

user B - FACEBOOK

user C - GOOGLE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set a "User Session Note" mapper to your client's mappers.
Set the User Session Note field to: identity_provider

[image: Session Note Mapper]

Note: you can use identity_provider_identity in User Session Note field to get its username from to identity provider https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#available-user-session-data

Answer (score 1):

Map metadata given in the access token, such as facebook/google user id, and import these to the keycloak user. If you then provide this metadata to the clients, they can see which identity broker that was used.

https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/server-adminstration-guide/content/topics/identity-broker/mappers.html

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I found an alternative solution to your problem (given that you attempt to reach the information via Java / Spring). Say that that you have concrete variables `user`, `realm` and `session` of type `UserModel`, `RealmModel` and `KeyCloakSession`, respectively. Then you can obtain the set of all federated identities associated to your user:

```
Set<FederatedIdentityModel> identitySet = session.users().getFederatedIdentities(user, realm);
```

Each instance of `FederatedIdentityModel` has a `#getIdentityProvider` method allowing you to obtain the name of your IdP in question.